# Week and day views using Xamarin-Forms-Labs Calendar

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xlabs

I am working on the Xforms calendar sample and I would like to add 2 new CalendarViews, modifed to show me just the calendar in a week view and a day view.

Does anyone have ever done something similar?

Comment: Can you show us exacly what you are doing? Can you add the relevant code? 'Xforms calendar sample' isn't helping us that much.

Comment: @jHilscher sure!

I'm working on this sample: https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/Calendar-Control
I didn't manage to create the week and day views.